# How to make a transparent overlay/tool window based on a PNG image (OS X)

Tags: macos, nswindow

Based on a PNG image I would like to make a floating tool window. The transparent areas of this floating window should be based on the transparent areas of the image. It could for example be an image of an arrow that could be moved around on the desktop pointing at something.

Comment: *It could for example be an image of an arrow that could be moved around on the desktop pointing at something* => you mean a mouse cursor?

Comment: Subclass `NSWindow` make it Opaque set an Opaque `NSView` as it's contentView  
Set `CALayer` on `NSView` with `[NSColor clearColor].CGColor;`
And put your Image inside the `CALayer` and put Window's level to something like `NSFloatingWindowLevel`

Comment: I don't mean a cursor - I meant an arrow that points to something independently of the cursor.

Comment: I'll try subclassing NSWindow as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `NSWindow` make it Non Opaque

set an Non Opaque `NSView` as it's contentView

Set `CALayer` on `NSView` with `[NSColor clearColor].CGColor;`

And put your Image inside the `CALayer` and put Window's level to something like `NSFloatingWindowLevel`